# How to use critsend with php?

Tags: php, email

I'm starting to use the critsend.com services. I'm trying to send mails using their [send API](http://www.critsend.com/documentation/code/php/).

Here is what I have tried:

```
include_once('php-connector.php');
$content = array('subject'=> 'My subject', 'html'=> 'my html' , 'text' =>'my test');

$param = array('tag'=>array('invoice1'), 'mailfrom'=> 'frommail@mysite.com', 'mailfrom_friendly'=> 'myName', 'replyto'=>'', 'replyto_filtered'=> 'true');

$emails[0] = array('email'=>'my-to-email@gmail.com', 'field1'=> 'test');

$mxm = new MxmConnect(False, True);

try {
  echo $j;
  print_r($mxm->sendCampaign($content, $param, $emails));
} catch (MxmException $e) {
 echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But this script doesn't send any mails. 
Am I using the send api in right way?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working for me"?

Comment: The above script doesn't send mails, also it doesn't output anything to the screen.

Comment: Ok, so the most likely culprit is your line that initiates `MxmConnect` - put that inside your try block and see if it outputs anything in the catch. Also remove `$j` - it's not defined anywhere (I know it's in the Critsend documentation :))

Comment: @scrowler Tried your suggestion. but it dint work.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't supposed to work but was supposed to help you identify your problem. Have you completed basic debugging steps i.e. turn on error reporting, check the value of each variable throughout your script and identified the point where it fails?